# How do I pass the type as a variable?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working with DynamoDB. I want to create a db adapter class (rather than viewing a bunch of copy/pasted code in various sections of the program) that can do the following:

```
DynamoDBMapper mapper = Dynamo.getMapper(SomeClassHere.TABLE_NAME);

DynamoDBQueryExpression<SomeClassHere> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<SomeClassHere>()
                .withHashKeyValues(passedInObjectHere);

        List<SomeClassHere> list = mapper.query(SomeClassHere, queryExpression);
```

so SomeClassHere would be the name of a class as its Type and used for mapping fields in the DynamoDBMapper as well.

I'd like to pass in an object parameter similar to this:

```
public void getList(IDynamoDBModel model) {
DynamoDBMapper mapper = Dynamo.getMapper(GetTheClassTypeFromTheModel);

DynamoDBQueryExpression<GetTheClassTypeFromTheModel> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<GetTheClassTypeFromTheModel>()
                .withHashKeyValues(model);

        List<GetTheClassTypeFromTheModel> list = mapper.query(GetTheClassTypeFromTheModel, queryExpression);

}
```

This way, instead of copy/pasting 'code for save', 'code for delete', 'code for get item' everywhere, I can simply:

- call a connection manager
- get a connection to the DynamoDb from it
- pass in the object with its preloaded values into the appropriate
  method (save, delete, getItem, etc...)

I realize that generics are used at compile time and it may be a fruitless effort but I reeeeally want to clean up this inherited code base.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with DynomoDB.

But according to my understanding you want to implement generic data access layer from DynamoDB. it can be achieve via generic and I have implement below code you to understand how you can achieve this.

Please ignore DynamoDB specification and this code won't work by just copy and paste. so makes sure to edit accordingly.

Implement DynamoTypeProvider interface.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface DynamoTypeProvider<DynamoType> {
    Class<DynamoType> getDynamoType();
}
```

Implement Generic Data access service for DyanamoDB as below.

```
public abstract class DynamoQueryService<DynamoType, DynamoDBModel extends DynamoTypeProvider<DynamoType>> {

    public List<DynamoType> getList(DynamoDBModel model) {
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = Dynamo.getMapper(model.getDynamoType());

        DynamoDBQueryExpression<DynamoType> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<DynamoType>()
                .withHashKeyValues(model);

        return mapper.query(model.getDynamoType(), queryExpression);

    }

}
```

Suppose Dynamo type is UserType and DynamoDBModel is User. 
from User we should be able to get Dynamo DB type UserType.

```
public class UserType {
  //your code. 
}

public class User implements DynamoTypeProvider<UserType>{
    //your code 
    @Override
    public Class<UserType> getDynamoType() {
        return UserType.class;
    }
```

Then implement specify model type data access service. here it is UserDynamoQueryService.

```
 public class UserDynamoQueryService extends DynamoQueryService<UserType, User> {



}
```

then you can get UserType as

```
    UserDynamoQueryService service = new UserDynamoQueryService();
    List<UserType> types = service.getList(new User());
```

Using Generic you can achieve this. 
please makes sure edit this accordingly.

Or you can try below example.

```
public class DynamoQueryService { 

    public <T, X> List<T> getList(X x, Class<T> tClass) {
            DynamoDBMapper mapper = Dynamo.getMapper(tClass);
            DynamoDBQueryExpression<T> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<T>()
                    .withHashKeyValues(x);

            return mapper.query(tClass, queryExpression);
        }

    }
```

And use as below.

```
DynamoQueryService queryService = new DynamoQueryService();
        List<UserType> userTypes = service.getList(new User(), UserType.class);
```

Then User dose not need to implement DynamoTypeProvider.